# ContentProvider database variables, where to put them?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Consider:

```
public static final String NOTE_ID = "_id";
public static final String TITLE = "title";
public static final String TEXT = "text";
```

3 columns in my sqlite database shown above to be used in a content provider,  where do I put these in the code below? where is the best place?

and what should I put in the NoteItems class that extends BaseColumns?

a little confused on the where to put what.

```
public class ProviderExample extends ContentProvider {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";
public static final String AUTHORITY = "package   com.example.contentproviderexample.providerexample";

public static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;

private static final int NOTES = 1;

private static final int NOTES_ID = 2;

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"
        + AUTHORITY + "/notes");

     static final String SINGLE_RECORD = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.providerexample";
     static final String MULTIPLE_RECORDS = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.providerexample";

 static {
        sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_NAME, NOTES);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_NAME + "/#", NOTES_ID);
    }

    public static interface NoteItems extends BaseColumns { }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
} // DatabaseHelper
```

EDIT:

I narrowed down the choice. It looks like 2 places that are best to put this code. One is inside ProviderExample extends ContentProvider class along with the other variables, and the other position is inside the DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper class, both are possible, but I don't know which of the two places is more correct. I have found examples of both ways being used.

Comment: Please don't add Android to the question title, the tag at the bottom is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 3 columns in my sqlite database shown above to be used in a content
>   provider, where do I put these in the code below? where is the best
>   place?
>
> and what should I put in the NoteItems class that extends BaseColumns?

This aren't really questions to be answered. I could say put them at the bottom of the class and I doubt it would help you.

When using a `ContentProvider` a good idea is to use a `Contract` class/interface in which to put all the provider related constants for easy access/change and also for (possible) public release(if you allow the provider to be used by other apps). This part is covered in the [guide for providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) available on the android developers site which I strongly recommend you to read.

I would move the `NotesItems` interface in its own file and put all constants in it(at least the ones you mention) and access them using `NotesItems._ID` etc